# Configuring build name and build id

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins 1.499 on RHEL 6.3.  At present, the build id/name is just an number or formed out of the build date and time.  But I want to have the build name as 0.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.1-MMDD-${BUILD_NUMBER} (That is, build number in that particular day).  The build-name-setter plugin just allows to set the display name and that too static.  How can I achieve the above stuff?

Regards,
Seenu.

Comment: have you tried the ZenTimestamp plugin? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

We've been able to achieve something similar using the [Version Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin).  You can configure what environment variable to stick the value in, how to make the value (even from other env variables), and whether or not to display the (default) build number or the value you had it create.